# Cannot read property 'isStream' of undefined with fluent-ffmpeg

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, ffmpeg

I have these lines of code

```
s3.getObject(getParams, function (err, response) {
        ffmpeg(response.Body)
            .size('640x360')
            .videoFilter({ filter: 'scale', options: [640, -1] })
            // .seekInput('3:00')
            .duration('0:08')
            .format('mp4')
            .on('error', function (err) {
                console.error(err, 'invalid ffmpeg conversion')
            })
            .on('start', function (start) {
                console.log(start, 'starting');
            })
            .on('progress', function (any) {
                console.log(any, 'progress')
            })
            .on('end', function () {
                s3.putObject({
                    Bucket: S3_CREDENTIALS.bucketName,
                    Key: newKey,
                    Body: fs.readSync(newKey),
                    ContentType: response.ContentType
                }, function (err, data) {
                    fs.unlinkSync(newKey)
                    if (err) {
                        res.json('ko')
                    } else {
                        res.json('ok')
                    }
                });
            })
            .output(fs.createWriteStream(newKey))
            .run()
    })
```

The reason because I create a file is that I cannot stream the fluent-ffmpeg output to the putObject stream body. Of course if there's a way to avoid to create a local file (and then delete it) is better

The error I get is a `fluent-ffmpeg` error saying `Error [TypeError]: Cannot read property 'isStream' of undefined`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

this code is actually working. a better solution is welcome.

```
const newKey = "preview_" + req.params.key
    const source = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject',getParams)
    ffmpeg({source})
        .size('640x360')
        .videoFilter({ filter: 'scale', options: [640, -1] })
        // .seekInput('3:00')
        .duration('0:08')
        .format('mp4')
        .on('end', function () {
            s3.putObject({
                Bucket: S3_CREDENTIALS.bucketName,
                Key: newKey,
                Body: fs.readFileSync(newKey),
                ContentType: 'video/mp4'
            }, function (err, data) {
                fs.unlinkSync(newKey)
                if (err) {
                    res.json('ko')
                } else {
                    res.json('ok')
                }
            });
        })
        .outputOptions([
            '-movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov',
            '-movflags +faststart'
        ])
        .toFormat('mp4')
        .save(newKey)
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this without having to use s3.getSignedUrl (and simply use response.Body from initial s3.getObject call)?